# API calls not running ansynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm working on a python client that will asynchronously download vinyl cover art. My problem is that I'm new to python (especially asynchronous python) and I don't think my code is running ansychronously. I have another client written in Node.js that is able to get approx. 40 images/sec whereas this python one is only managing to get around 1.5/sec.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

from os import path,makedirs

caa_base_url = "https://coverartarchive.org/release"
image_download_dir = path.realpath('images')
# small,large, None = Max
image_size = None
async def getImageUrls(release_mbid,session):
  async with session.get(f'{caa_base_url}/{release_mbid}') as resp:
    if resp.status == 404 or resp.status == 403:
      return
    return [release_mbid,await resp.json()]

async def getImage(url,session):
  try:
    async with session.get(url) as resp:
      return [url,await resp.read()]
  except (aiohttp.ServerDisconnectedError):
    return await getImage(url,session)

async def getMBIDs(mb_page_url):
  async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(mb_page_url) as resp:
      mb_json = await resp.json()

    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as caa_session:
      for release in mb_json["releases"]:
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(getImageUrls(release["id"],caa_session))
        tasks.append(task)
      responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

      async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as caa_image_session:
        for response in responses:
          if response is not None:
            caaTasks = []
            release_mbid = response[0]
            result = response[1]
            for image in result["images"]:
              if image["front"] == True:
                caaTask = asyncio.ensure_future(getImage(image["image"],caa_session))
                caaTasks.append(caaTask)
            image_responses = await asyncio.gather(*caaTasks)
            for image_response in image_responses:
              image_url = image_response[0]
              image_binary = image_response[1]
              new_file_dir = path.join(image_download_dir,release_mbid)
              if not path.isdir(new_file_dir):
                makedirs(new_file_dir)
              file_name = image_url[image_url.rfind("/")+1:]
              file_path = path.join(new_file_dir,file_name)
              new_file = open(file_path,'wb')
              new_file.write(image_binary)          

mb_base_url = "https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/release"
num_pages = 100
releases_per_page = 100

mb_page_urls = []

async def getMBPages():
  for page_index in range(num_pages):
    await getMBIDs('%s?query=*&type=album&format=Vinyl&limit=%s&offset=%s&fmt=json' % (mb_base_url,releases_per_page,page_index*releases_per_page))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(getMBPages())
```

P.S. The sleep is because musicbrainz api limits to 1 request/sec

Comment: I don't understand. You say there's a limit of 1req/s yet your NodeJs gets 40/s? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: It goes through two apis. The first is musicbrainz which is used to get all the vinyls unique identifiers (mbids). The second is coverartarchive which is where the actual images are downloaded from using the retrieved mbids. Only musicbrainz has rate limiting.

Comment: Also I should be clear I am able to get 1.5 images/sec not 1.5 req/sec. Some of the mbids don't have any cover art associated with them.

Comment: The code looks correct. Have you tried adding prints at the beginning and end of `getImageUrls` and `getImage` to check if they are really not running in parallel? Maybe there are other differences (cookies or other headers) that lead to the performance difference between Node and aiohttp.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `getMBPages` sleeps unnecessarily long. It could be smarter and `await asyncio.sleep(remaining)`, with `remaining` being calculated as `time.time() - initial_time`, and `initial_time` being the `time.time()` before `await getMBIDs(...)`. Perhaps the Node.js code does something like that?

Comment: @user4815162342 I made another post that is a more clear on the issues. It also includes a node.js equivalent. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349205/aysnc-python-dragging-balls-compared-to-node-js